# Removing an element from a list based on a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to remove an element (in this case a tuple) from one list based on a condition (if satisfied) in  another list.

I have 2 lists (list of tuples).

```
List1 = [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]


List2 = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2)]
```

List1 is basically computed from the following code.

```
import pandas as pd    
mapping = {'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],'ID': [1,2,3,2]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(mapping)
comb = df['name'].to_list()
List1 = list(combinations(comb,2))

# mapping the elements of the list to an 'ID' from the dataframe and creating a list based on the following code
List2 = [(df['ID'].loc[df.name == x].item(), df['ID'].loc[df.name == y].item()) for (x, y) in List1]
```

Now I need to apply a condition here; looking at List2, I need to look at all tuples in List2 and see if there is any tuple with same 'ID's in it. For example, in List2 I see there is (2,2). So, I want to go back to List1 based on this remove the corresponding tuple which yielded this (2,2) pair.

Essentially my final revised list should be this:

```
RevisedList = [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd')]
```

('b','d') should be removed because they yield (2,2) same IDs in a set

Comment: List1 is a list of tuple, but List2 is a list of list of tuples, is that correct? Also add the expected output for the input in the question

Comment: List2 is also a list of tuples like this [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (2, 2), (3, 2)]

Comment: Fix the question to reflect that, also what's the expected output?  you say (2,2) is same in List to and ('b','d') goes why does ('b','c') or ('a','b') not go? Please add more clarity to the explanation

Comment: It's difficult to understand the relationship between id and letters. If `b` is `2` why does `(2, 2)` correspond to `(b,d)` and not `(b,b)`. Do you just want to remove the elements in List1 that correspond to tuples with identical members in List2?

Comment: Sure @DeveshKumarSingh I will fix the question now.  I will edit the question to be more clear

Comment: removing pandas, since no pandas operations are required here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List1 = [('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('a','d'), ('b','c'), ('b','d')]
List2 = [(1,2), (1,3), (1,2), (2,3), (2,2)]
new_List1 = [elem for index,elem in enumerate(List1) if List2[index][0]!=List2[index][1]]
// Result: [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c')]
```

It is not entirely clear but is this what you are looking for? new_List1 only contains those indexes where at that index List2 has two different numbers in the tuple